# Different results when using scipy.stats.ttest_ind for whole arrays vs. for two vectors

Tags: python, scipy

I am doing voxel-wise comparisons between two groups (men & women) using multiple t-tests. For that I am using `scipy.stats.ttest_ind`. I have 541443 voxels as dependent variables on which I want to perform independent t-tests. Everything seems to work fine, however when I check the results and doing single t-tests on random picked voxels I get different results for them.

Here's my code:

```
statistics,p_values = ttest_ind(male_data,female_data)
```

produces: array([-5.23764997e-16, -1.59544316e-15,  7.88216339e-16, ...,
        1.11783465e-15, -2.22874323e-16, -9.35188323e-16]) for the t-values

```
single_stat,single_p_value = ttest_ind(female_data[:,0],male_data[:,0])
```

produces: -4.3805762173832176e-16 as t-value

I expect the output for the first t-test to be equal (so either ~ -5.237 or ~ -4.380). Does anyone know what could have gone wrong here?

I also tried out a third method which is doing multiple t-tests using a for-loop. There seems to be a consistent effect that the outcome of the for-loop-method is always the same as the output for the single-t-test method (which makes sense, because it is basically doing multiple single `ttest_ind` and then appending the output of each t-test to a list). However both results differ from the output of `ttest_ind` for **the whole array**. I also sliced the data down to different sizes as suggested in the comments and I find the paradox effect that the results of the three methods (or two, because for-loop and single t-test seem to be always the same) become more and more similar but the returned t-values and p-values become incredibly small or large. Also, *Spyder* crashes when I want to click on the output of `ttest_ind` for the whole array in the last case (n=5).

```
n_rows = 150
Output from for-loop method (first t-value in the list):
t-value: -0.050583527798906465
p-value: 0.9596912767683707

Output from the t-test performed on only the first column:
t-value: -0.050583527798906465
p-value: 0.9596912767683707

Output from the t-test performed on the whole array (first t-value):
t-value: -0.050583527798907256
p-value: 0.9596912767683701

---------------------------------------
n_rows = 75
Output from for-loop method (first t-value in the list):
t-value: 0.9760289069224989
p-value: 0.33064277748038773

Output from the t-test performed on only the first column:
t-value: 0.9760289069224989
p-value: 0.33064277748038773

Output from the t-test performed on the whole array (first t-value):
t-value: 0.9760289069224984
p-value: 0.33064277748038795

---------------------------------------
n_rows = 5
Output from for-loop method (first t-value in the list):
t-value: 6111430044112607.0
p-value: 5.755396703077005e-124

Output from the t-test performed on only the first column:
t-value: 6111430044112607.0
p-value: 5.755396703077005e-124

Output from the t-test performed on the whole array (first t-value):
t-value: 6111430044112607.0
p-value: 5.755396703077005e-124

---------------------------------------
```

Comment: It's [not obvious](https://ideone.com/iycSU8) how to reproduce this problem. Anything you can do to show us how to reproduce the problem would be helpful. What is the shape and dtype of `male_data` and `female_data`? If you slice the data in half (using `data[len(data)//2]`) do you still see the discrepancy? (If so, keep slicing in half.) Using bisection perhaps you can construct a [mcve] (or the process will unveil a clue about what is going wrong).

Comment: Correction: `data[:len(data)//2]`, not `data[len(data)//2]`.

Comment: You're right, if I slice the data in half the problem disappears! Any idea what the problem could be? Maybe an overflow problem?

The shape of `male_data` is `(151,541443)` and the shape of `female_data` is `(155,541443)`, both have the dtype float64.

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing this. Have you tried other slices? The goal is to find a data set which is small enough to post which exhibits the problem. If it an overflow problem, it might be useful to examine `data.mean(axis=0)`, and `np.var(data, 0, ddof=1)` and perhaps plot a histogram of some slices to see that the data looks like it comes from the distribution you'd expect (if you are fortunate enough to have that information).

Comment: Or you might want to [use a debugger](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pdb.html) to step through the `ttest_ind` calculation to try to get understanding of where the calculation is going wrong. The [source code for ttest_ind](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/stats.py#L4442) is written in Python and is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: @unutbu check my edit on the post: The problem did *not* really disappear, the differences between the two methods only got so small that I overlooked them.

Answer (score 0):

The results of floating point arithmetic can depend on the order in which operations are performed, and that order can change depending on the layout of the array in memory. The magnitude of the effect depends on the sample size.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = np.random.default_rng(7435282483469345)

func = np.mean

# For several different sample sizes
ns = np.logspace(1, 7, 30).astype(int)

err = []
for n in ns:
  # Generate n x 2 samples
  x = rng.random(size=(n, 2))

  # Compute the mean along axis 0
  y = func(x, axis=0)

  # Compute the mean of each column separately
  z = [func(x[:, i]) for i in range(x.shape[-1])]

  # Record the difference in the 0th result
  err.append(abs(y[0] - z[0]))

plt.loglog(ns, err)
plt.xlabel('Sample size')
plt.ylabel(f'Absolute difference')
plt.title(f'The effect of sample size on np.{func.__name__} discrepancy')
```

[image]

The effect disappears if you keep the default row-major order and work along `axis=-1`, or if you convert the array to column-major order (`np.asfortranarray`) and keep `axis=0`.